# How to do a React-Navigation Route? (Tabs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I created an application with React native expo. I chose the React-Navigation tabs feature. When I created a new screen, it appears in the Tab section. I dont want this. I just want him to go to that page when he clicks on the link. But it's added to the Tab section.

```
const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  CampaignStack,
  MenuStack
});

tabNavigator.path = '';

export default tabNavigator;
```

I will be redirected from the menu screen to the login screen. But I don't want it in the Tabs section.

I'd appreciate it if you helped to solve my problem.

Comment: use createStackNavigator instead of createBottomTabNavigator . Check the link https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html

Comment: But I want to use it as tabs. Just don't appear on every screen tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a stackNavigator for that.

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ FirstPage: HomeScreen, SecondPage: SecondScreen });
```

and when creating that, from the first page, you can use for the action
`Navigation.navigate(YOUR_PAGE_ID);`

Please refer to react-navigation [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html) for more info